# Autoload and Namespaces php

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I have this structure file:

```
Classes
      Connection.php
      Admin
           User.php
admin
     index.php

autoload.php
```

This are my files. They are very simple but still I don't know why is giving me error:

This is the autoload.php

```
/*** class Loader ***/
function autoLoader($class){

    $ggFileName = str_replace("\\","/",$class);
    $file = $ggFileName . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)){

        include $file;
        return true;
    }

        return false;
}

/*** register the loader functions ***/
spl_autoload_register('autoLoader');
```

My file admin/index.php

```
 include_once('../boostrap.php');

 use \Classes\Admin\User;

 if($_REQUEST['submit'] === 'Login'){

       User::login();

 }



<strong>Login</strong>

<form  name="login" method="post" >

    user:<input type="text" name="user" /> <br/>
    password:<input type="password" name="password" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Login" />

</form>
```

My Classes/Admin/User.php   --->

```
 namespace Classes\Admin;

use \Classes\Connection;
use PDO;

class User {

/**
* Auth Login user
*
*/
public static function login(){

    try{

        echo "try to login";

    }catch(\Exception $e){

         echo $e->Message();
    }

}


}
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Classes\Admin\User' not found in /home/germancv/public_html/admin/index.php on line 8
```

I think I am using the namespace wrong ...

Comment: where have you included your `autoload.php`

Comment: Try dumping out `$ggFileName`, I would suspect it's being used as an absolute path, i.e. from /. Using `$file = __DIR__ . $ggFileName . '.php';` might be what you're after.

Comment: Ya it make sense !! I will try to see if is that. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

**Use the [PRS-4 Autoload standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for naming namespaces which makes autoloading very easy.**

In your case for USER class `namespace ProjectName\Classes\Admin`

**Organize files and folders that matches with the Namespace.**

**Define a ROOT_URI path**

E.g.  `define('ROOT_URI', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\XAMPP\htdocs\')`

**Make the Autoloader**

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $file = ROOT_URI. str_replace('\\', '/', $class) .'.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
    }
});
```

**If you want to use the class and create an object**

```
 $user = ProjectName\Admin\User();
```

or

```
use ProjectName\Admin\User as User; 
$user = new User();
```

**If you want a similar and simple working example for Organizing Namespaces**

Have a look at my code in [Github](https://github.com/AvidahRai/barcode-generator-v1) and also see the [init.php](https://github.com/AvidahRai/barcode-generator-v1/blob/master/BarcodeGenerator/init.php) file